# Add a line break in jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I am calling these variables which are question in a quiz (multiStr).

How can I insert a line break? I have tried \n and "+

If it's not possible, can I insert some HTML in the middle to break up the question to multiple lines?

```
var multiStr = [                        
    {
        "question"      :   " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius pharetra tellus.",    
        "choices"       :   [
                                "True",
                                "False",              
                            ],
        "correct"       :   "False",
        "explanation"   :   " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius pharetra tellus, ac porta sem sollicitudin eget.",
    },
```

Comment: What function do you use to put the string on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

/n is working fine for line breaks try both examples.

```
var a = "hello test \n the code ";
console.log(a)


var multiStr = [                        
{
    "question"      :   " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \n consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius pharetra tellus.",    
    "choices"       :   [
                            "True",
                            "False",              
                        ],
    "correct"       :   "False",
    "explanation"   :   " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius pharetra tellus, ac porta sem sollicitudin eget.",
}];
alert(multiStr[0].question);
```

In Html you can use `<br/>` for line breaks

Answer (score 0):

use \n and instead of append method use .empty().html("you text"+"\n") or use `<br>`